# How to generate Android app bundle for ionic 3 signed apk

Tags: android-studio, ionic3

I have generated the apk using the command:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

after that I have generated the key for Play Store using the command:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore myapp-release-key.keystore -alias com.exel.myapp -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

later I have signed using jarsigner command:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore myapp-release-key.keystore platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\release\app-release-unsigned.apk com.exel.myapp
```

finally I am bundling using Zipalign with this command:

```
C:\Users\Exel\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\29.0.0\zipalign -v 4 platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\release\app-release-unsigned.apk myapp-release-signed.apk
```

When I am uploading the app to the Play Store it’s giving a warning like unoptimized code “please bundle using an Android app bundle”.

So, I need suggestions and solutions for this problem. I will be very thankful for this forum if I can fix this with your help.

When I am trying to do an Android apk/bundle using an Android Studio 3.4.1 it’s giving me a warning like “Android Gradle Plugin version should be 3.2 or higher”. When I am clicking the update button it’s getting dismissed and continuously showing the same message every time.

“Android Gradle Plugin version should be 3.2 or higher”.

Answer (score 1):

If you are missing one step, try this. I am using this command to build a release app:

> To generate Keystore file:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

> Build android

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

> To sign the unsigned APK, run the jarsigner tool which is also included in the JDK:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk alias_name

zipalign -v 4 HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk HelloWorld.apk

apksigner verify exercisetips.apk
```

In the above command you are not using this one:

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs C:\ionic\myapp\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\release\app-release-unsigned.apk
```

Let me know if it's works for you or not. Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Thanks mate, this one helps a lot!

Comment: I upgraded to plaftorm android 10.1.2 from 7.0.0 and now it's using gradle and produces .AAB file
How can I tell the build command (cordova build android --release -- --keystore="..." --storePassword= ....) to produce .apk in addition to the .aab ? I don't care to publish on Google Play.  thank you.

Comment: there is no issue in .AAB file, play store let you upload file.

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward way is always command line scripts...
This is the sequence of steps to prepare deploy to production an optimized bundle.

1. create package 
   `ionic cordova build android --prod --release`
2. build app bundle (optimization) **KEY STEP** 
   `cd [YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER_PATH]\platforms\android`
   `gradlew.bat bundle`
3. sign the app bundle 
   `cd [YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER_PATH]\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\bundle\release`
   `jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore "[YOUR_certificate-keys.jks_FILE_PATH]" app-release.aab [YOUR_NAME] -storepass [YOUR_CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD]`
4. Just upload your boundle (*.aab)
   `YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER_PATH\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\bundle\release\app-release.aab`